# CTFontCopyName Returns null for the kCTFontSampleTextNameKey

Tags: objective-c, macos, ctfont, ctfontref

I am trying to get the Sample text of a font.This is my coding.

```
    NSString *fontFilePath=@"/Volumes/Work/Mac/Fonts/FONT FOLDER/Times New Roman Bold.ttf";
    CFStringRef aCFString = (CFStringRef)fontFilePath;
    CTFontRef fontRef = CTFontCreateWithName(aCFString, 0.0,NULL);           
    CFStringRef sampleText=CTFontCopyName(fontRef,kCTFontSampleTextNameKey);
    NSLog(@"%@",sampleText);
```

It returns null as the result. But for the `kCTFontCopyrightNameKey`, `kCTFontLicenseURLNameKey` etc.... It returns the correct value. For only the `kCTFontSampleTextNameKey` it returns `null`. May I know how can I able to get the sampletext of the given font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That font just doesn't have the requested value. Either handle that case or edit the font and add your own value.

If you want to **add the missing value** into font, you need to use some font editor. Sorry, don't know any (but bet google search might find a few).

If you want to **handle the case** in your own code, for example for built-in system fonts, here's some sample code:

```
CFStringRef sampleText = CTFontCopyName(fontRef,kCTFontSampleTextNameKey);
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", (NSString *)sampleText ? (NSString *)sampleText : @""],
if (sampleText) CFRelease(sampleText);
```

Comment: May I know how can I able to add the value to the font?